# with this inequality condition $xyz(x+y+z)=3$

Tags: inequality

Let $x,y,z$ be postive real numbers such that $xyz(x+y+z)=3$,show that
$$\dfrac{1}{x^2}+\dfrac{1}{y^2}+\dfrac{1}{z^2}+\dfrac{54}{(x+y+z)^2}\ge 9$$

I found this problem on [math magazine](https://www.awesomemath.org/wp-content/uploads/mr_6_2014_solutions2.pdf) and the solution does not hold,see:
[image]

and I want to use Holder's inequality
$$\dfrac{1}{x^2}+\dfrac{1}{y^2}+\dfrac{1}{z^2}\ge\dfrac{27}{(x+y+z)^2}$$
so we must show that the following inequality is true
$$\dfrac{81}{(x+y+z)^2}\ge 9$$
In fact, this also does not hold. Because $$xyz(x+y+z)=3\Longrightarrow x+y+z\ge 3$$

**Now I suspect if $(1)$ is correct? Although I have not found any counter-example so far.**

Comment: $(x,y,z) = (\frac 12, \frac 12, 3)$ is a counterexample for (1). Also it seems like the author have wrongly used the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: pqr method also works.

Answer (score 0):

We'll prove a stronger inequality.

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positives such that $ abc(a+b+c)=3$. Prove that:

$\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}+\frac{72}{(a+b+c)^2}\ge 11$

Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Hence, the condition does not depend on $v^2$.

In another hand, $\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}+\frac{72}{(a+b+c)^2}=\frac{9v^4-6uw^3}{w^6}+\frac{8}{u^2}$ is an increasing function of $v^2$.

Thus, by $uvw$ (http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h278791) it remains to check one case only: $b=a$ and $c=\sqrt{a^2+\frac{3}{a^2}}-a$, which gives

$\frac{2}{a^2}+\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{a^2+\frac{3}{a^2}}-a\right)^2}+\frac{72}{\left(\sqrt{a^2+\frac{3}{a^2}}+a\right)^2}\geq11$ or

$146a^8+219a^4-99a^2+18\geq142a^6\sqrt{a^4+3}$.

Let $a^2=x$. Hence, we need to prove that

$(146x^4+219x^2-99x+18)^2\geq142^2x^6(x^2+3)$ or

$(x-1)^2(128x^6+256x^5+768x^4-1932x^3+1281x^2-324x+36)\geq0$, which is obvious.